# PHP Check For One Letter and One Digit

Tags: php, regex, string

How can I check if a string is at least one letter and one digit in PHP? Can have special characters, but basically needs to have one letter and one digit.

Examples:

```
$string = 'abcd'   //Return false
$string = 'a3bq'   //Return true
$string = 'abc#'   //Return false
$string = 'a4#e'   //Return true
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the 'alphanumeric' thing was bugging me, because that means it contains only letters and/or numbers. This makes more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
if (preg_match('/[A-Za-z]/', $string) & preg_match('/\d/', $string) == 1) {
    // string contains at least one letter and one number
}
```

Comment: @ikegami: you can do it both ways. Phil numerically adds and compares the result against a value of 2. If you'd throw away the `== 2`, you could also replace the `+` against `&&` and do a logical AND.

Comment: @ikegami As `preg_match()` returns an integer (`0` or `1`), I thought the addition and comparison to `2` was more appropriate. Could have also use `a & b == 1`

Comment: The point is that could have used `a && b`. Period. No `== 2`, no `== 1`. Much clearer.

Comment: @ikegami I disagree entirely. Using an explicit comparison is much more robust than an implicit one. I guess it's down to personal taste but I simply do not like relying on type conversions in comparison statements

Comment: @Phil, both conditions of my comparison were explicitly speicified, so I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @ikegami: disagree. To me the numeric way is more clear. The `a && b` way will be confusing for those not being aware of the transparent `(int) -> (bool)` casting PHP would transparently do in that case.

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen, No casting is involved. If you insist on specifying redundant redundancies, you can use `preg_match()==1 && preg_match()==1` and still be fairly clear. Adding addition into the mix heavily increases the mental load.

Comment: @ikegami: Hm, maybe I better should've said "automatic conversion" instead of "transparent casting", I guess. The logical AND `&&` requires boolean arguments. If they are not, PHP will [automatically convert them to booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

Comment: @Jürgen Thelen, The docs don't say *anything* about `&&` requiring a `boolean`, just a TRUE or FALSE value (all uppercase), and those aren't `boolean`. The fact that `&&` exited long before `boolean` values did is a pretty sure sign of this too. As far as I can tell, there is no `boolean` value created, so there is no "automatic conversion" or "transparent casting".

Comment: Even if there was a cast, so what?

Comment: @ikegami See [Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). `$a && $b` evaluates to **TRUE** if both *$a* and *$b* are **TRUE**. **TRUE** is a boolean type. If either are not explicitly booleans, they will be [automatically converted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting). It's this automatic conversion I'm not fond of, hence the explicit comparison in my answer

Comment: @Phil, No. `True` is a `boolean`, but not **TRUE**. `True` is **TRUE**, but so is `1`.

Comment: @ikegami Besides SO formatting, I fail to see the difference. From the manual... *To specify a boolean literal, use the keywords TRUE or FALSE. Both are case-insensitive.* `1` is an integer that when used in a logical operation, is automatically converted to boolean `true`

Comment: @Phil, Case-insensitive? wow, ok, I stand corrected, the docs does imply a casting. But like said I said, it's of no import whether there is a casting or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match('/\pL/', $string) && preg_match('/\p{Nd}/', $string)
```

or

```
preg_match('/\pL.*\p{Nd}|\p{Nd}.*\pL/', $string)
```

or

```
preg_match('/^(?=.*\pL)(?=.*\p{Nd})/', $string)
```

or

```
preg_match('/^(?=.*\pL).*\p{Nd}/', $string)
```

---

I'm not sure if `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` or if it matches decimal digits in PHP, so I didn't use it. Use whichever of `\d`, `[0-9]` and `\p{Nd}` that matches that right thing.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're looking for is `^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$`

In use:

```
if( preg_match( "/.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*/", $string ) )
     echo( "Valid" );
else
     echo( "Invalid." );
```

Comment: I removed the first "`.*`" because it just led to useless backtracking. I removed the trailing "`.*$`" because that always matches.

Comment: What string did you test against? I tested my changes against the strings the OP provided. Man, what you have now is even worst that what you started with. If you're going to use lookaheads, `preg_match("/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])/", $string)` and `preg_match("/^(?=.*\d).*[a-zA-Z]/", $string)` are much faster, especially in the case where there is no match. (Up to N*N checks instead of up to N*N*N checks.)

Answer (score -1):

That should work if latin chars only and numbers:

```
if (preg_match('/[a-z0-9]+/i', $search_string)) { ... has at least one a-zA-Z0-9 ... }
```

Comment: Sorry, should be more attentive to the question :) @Phil's solution is correct one.